# Calling jQuery methods on dynamically created elements in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that runs jQuery just fine, except on dynamically created elements, when it invokes the following error: `Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

A simplified version of the code in question:

```
$('#add-dropdown-button').click(function() {
    var newDropdown = '<select id="testDropdown"></select>';
    $('td').append(newDropdown);
    $('#newDropdown').append('<option value="1">Some Choice</option>');
});
```

The first 2 lines of the function execute, and the `<select>` element is added, but the last line throws the error, presumably because that `<select>` didn't exist from the beginning, Chrome thinks I'm trying to run some kind of inline script.

Is this a bug or am I approaching it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id of your dropdown is 'testDropdown', not 'newDropdown'. Try this:

```
$('#add-dropdown-button').click(function() {
    var newDropdown = '<select id="testDropdown"></select>';
    $('td').append(newDropdown);
    $('#testDropdown').append('<option value="1">Some Choice</option>');
});
```

Or simply:

```
$('#add-dropdown-button').click(function() {
    $('td').append('<select id="testDropdown"><option value="1">Some Choice</option></select>');
});
```